# Data from firebase firestore in Flatlist in react native won't render

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

My data from firebase firestore won't render in react native Flatlist. Does anyone know why? It should render out 3 tasks in the list, but it's completely blank when I run my app.

```
const [list, setList] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
        firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(uid).collection('tasks').get((snapshot) => {
            var data = snapshot.docs;
            data.forEach((doc) => {
                setList({
                    key: doc.id,
                    task : doc.data().task,
                })
            })
        })
    });

        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text style={styles.title}>Here is your tasks for today</Text>
                    <FlatList style={{width: '100%'}}
                        data={list}
                        keyExtractor={(item) => item.key}
                        renderItem={({item}) => {
                            return(
                                <View>
                                    <Text>{item.task}</Text>
                                </View>
                            )
                        }}
                    />
```

Comment: it would help if you can also console.log(data) so we can see your response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const [list, setList] = useState([])


useEffect(() => {
 firebase
  .firestore()
  .collection('users')
  .doc(uid)
  .collection('tasks');
  .get()
  .then((snapshot) => {

    const docList = []

    snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      docList.push(doc.data());
    })

    setList(docList);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error)
  })
}, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

flatlist data needs to be an array

this makes lists an object which it won't render

```
setList({
                    key: doc.id,
                    task : doc.data().task,
                })
```

i guess this will work

```
 firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(uid).collection('tasks').get((snapshot) => {
        var data = snapshot.docs;
let FirebaseArray = []
        data.forEach((doc) => {
FirebaseArray.push({
                key: doc.id,
                task : doc.data().task,
            })
          
        })
  setList(FirebaseArray)
    })
```